# BeanInitializationException: DispatcherServlet needs exactly 1 strategy for interface [org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to run a simple Spring MVC project, but getting error. Lots of similar questions here but none have worked for me till now.

### Here is what the error page contains:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: DispatcherServlet needs exactly 1 strategy for interface [org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getDefaultStrategy(DispatcherServlet.java:754)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initFlashMapManager(DispatcherServlet.java:709)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:448)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:432)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:768)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1058)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet$ContextRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1055)
    org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.onApplicationEvent(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:51)
    org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEventInternal(SourceFilteringListener.java:96)
    org.springframework.context.event.SourceFilteringListener.onApplicationEvent(SourceFilteringListener.java:68)
    org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.
```

### Here is my web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

### Here is the spring-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I've tried almost every Spring MVC HTTP error 500 solution out there. But they are not solving the error I'm getting. What is causing the error, and how can I solve it?

### Here is the controller:

```
package com.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class UserLoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/submit")
public ModelAndView submit() {
    String message = "Hello Everyone";
    return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you implementing FlashMapmanager? Is your base-package a Controller package, then that's wrong. Also, you saw that the root-cause is FlashMapManager, you should have posted some information about it as to where you are using it and all.

Comment: Your controller is a problem, which you have not posted. Read this : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMapManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your help Borg, but I have not implemented FlashMapmanager anywhere nor my base package is controler.

Comment: Yes, but your config says your base-package is your Controller package, repair it.  Also, what is your intention with that Controller method, because it does nothing. Try returning a String with name of JSP file without extension.

Answer (score 0):

The exception '*BeanInitializationException: DispatcherServlet needs exactly 1 strategy for interface [org.springframework.web.servlet.FlashMapManager]*' will be thrown since DispatcherServlet **needs exactly 1 strategy for interface but here it is getting more than 1 dependency**.

Class DispatcherServlet: http://javadox.com/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java.html

[image]

It means you are including more than one jar for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet.
***Try to add only the needed jars and remove other jars.*** For a simple Spring MVC program the below are the required jar files.

[image: Include only these jar files to run]